# <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> not working

Tags: html

I'm having problems getting my new webpage to respond properly to

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to display on a portrait iPad.

The webpage I've built as my template is http://mattkingston.com/brass-quintet-music/jazz-and-dixieland-for-brass-quintet.php and I've included the meta tag both on this page, and in the various php components. I have everything contained within a 900px div. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you intend to happen on an iPad? It seems that your container is always 900px wide.

Comment: You have lots of invalid html code, first off you have multiple html tags, but there are more errors too. Go here, paste your source code and click "Check", then fix all the issues and it should work. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea